# Can't get push notifications in Distribution but only in development

Tags: ios, push-notification, ssl-certificate

I having problems with push notifications. I recently uploaded my app to the appstore. When I was testing the app on the device I was receiving my push notifications. But when I now downloaded my app from the app store I don't receive them any more.

I followed the following [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12).

This is what I've done
I requested in my keychain a certificate request. This generated a .CSR file for me. Now in itunes connect I have created an APP ID where I enabled push notifications services.

Here I used the same .CSR for creating a development and an production certificate. 
The next step was that I downloaded the Production certificate and created a CK.PEM file with the following commands.

```
$ openssl x509 -in aps_production.cer -inform der 
    -out mosCert.pem

$ openssl pkcs12 -nocerts -out mosKey.pem -in mosKey.p12
Enter Import Password: 
MAC verified OK
Enter PEM pass phrase: 
Verifying - Enter PEM pass phrase:
```

This mosKey.p12 I exported from my keychain.

```
$ cat PushChatCert.pem PushChatKey.pem > ck.pem
```

Finally in my webservice code I have said that it should use now this ck.pem for sending pushnotifications.

But for some reason or another I don't get push notifications when I have downloaded the app from the app store.

Can anybody help me with this ?

**EDIT**

This is how I code sign my project

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced such situation myself and in my case the app did not receive any push notifications because it was accidentally built with a wrong bundle identifier.

Answer (score 0):

Sandbox: gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com, port 2195. (for the development)

Production: gateway.push.apple.com, port 2195. (for the release)